# Objective-CからSwiftへの変換

Tags: swift, xcode, swift2, xcode7

Objective-CからSwiftに書き直しているのですがうまく書き直せません。

## Objective-C

```
NSMutableDictionary * queryPublicKey = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[queryPublicKey setObject:(__bridge id)kSecClassKey forKey:(__bridge id)kSecClass];
[queryPublicKey setObject:publicTag forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrApplicationTag];
[queryPublicKey setObject:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyType];
```

## Swift

```
var queryPublicKey = NSMutableDictionary()
    queryPublicKey = [kSecClass: kSecClassKey,
                      kSecAttrApplicationTag: keychainIdentifierData,
                      kSecAttrKeyType: kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA]
```

Objective-Cを元に書き直すと

> 「Value of type 'CFString' does not conform to expected dictionary key type 'NSCopying'」

とエラーを吐きます。
何かしら一手間必要なのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var queryPublicKey = NSMutableDictionary()
queryPublicKey = [kSecClass as NSString: kSecClassKey,
                  kSecAttrApplicationTag as NSString: keychainIdentifierData,
                  kSecAttrKeyType as NSString: kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA]
```

`CFString` を `NSString` にキャストする必要があります。